# Terraform workspace > Can we ignore error?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I did recently my first Azure devops pipeline using Terraform task.
I read tutorial about terraform workspace and try to apply it on release pipeline.

1. On first stage: i have a TF task which create a workspace 'dev' and I do confirm that it works well
2. On second stage: same task and i create a workspace 'test'

However when i run a second release TF returns an error stated that workspace 'dev' (or 'test') already exists which is true and normal. So in Azure Devops i tick box 'continue on error'.

As you may guess, all my release works but i get a warning because of existing workspace. Do you have a ninja tip to ignore error when i run command

```
terraform workspace new dev
```

Maybe it exists an argument which hides the output error.

Comment: You would probably want to select the workspace and create if that fails.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your reply. Good approach but i still get an error returned in all case. I wonder if it exists an argument we can add to ignore output error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creation of workspaces is not something I would typically expect to see in a routine Terraform pipeline.

Instead, workspaces are either established once when initially setting up the configuration (remaining unchanged in ongoing routine updates) *or* the workspaces are being used for temporary development work, and so they'd be created manually in the developer's working environment by running the `terraform workspace new` command directly.

When running Terraform in automation, a pipeline will typically start by running `terraform init` and then run other commands like `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`. If you need to select a non-default workspace, you can set the environment variable `TF_WORKSPACE` before running any commands, and then Terraform will use that workspace for all operations. As mentioned above, you should establish the workspace once before setting up the pipeline, so that the pipeline will just use the workspace that already exists or generate an error if it does not exist, prompting you to do the one-off setup step to create it.

Comment: Thx martin for the tip. I applied the TF_WORKSPACE and it does the job as you explained. However in our automation process we have multiple agent running. Some of them are totally new (i mean never use TF). In this case i would like 'use this workspace and if not present then create it' without any error message or one-off setup to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform don't have a create if not exist option as of now, but there is an GitHub issue opened for select or create if not exist

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16191

how ever there are some workaround mentioned on the same trail

one workaround is

`terraform workspace select $env_name || terraform workspace new $env_name`

so it will select workspace of exists else it will create

Comment: Hi Ashmil, solution described in your link look tremendous and match with exactly what i need. Unfortunately it seems that '||' is not valid command anymore since TF 0.12.8. I run latest version TF 1.1.7 and get error message "The token '||' is not a valid statement separator in this version.". Do you have alternative ?